# Is there a BNF type grammar available for Purescript?

Tags: bnf, purescript, ebnf, abnf

Is there a `BNF` type grammer description of the `Purescript` language?

It is hard to get a good handle on the language when the syntax is buried and scattered into various documentation of concepts and intent and so forth.

Comment: PureScript doesn't have an official spec yet. It hasn't yet reached 1.0

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Isn't there a working ABNF that directs its development or is part of its parsing?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to that would be the [`Parser.y`](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/blob/master/lib/purescript-cst/src/Language/PureScript/CST/Parser.y) file, in the `purescript-cst` sub-project.

Comment: Thanks. That YACC file looks interesting.